# How change distance between icon and title in ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-actionbaractivity

I use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in my app.

I can set icon by `getSupportActionBar().setIcon()`. And set title text by `toolbar.setTitle()`.

But distance between icon and title is 0 as on pic:
[image]

How I can change distance between icon and title programatically (without custom ImageView and TextView inside Toolbar)?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is adding `app:titleMarginStart` in the xml `Toolbar` declaration

Here is an example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:titleMarginStart="32dp"/>
```